# SQL Query Help Using SYSDATE

Tags: sql

Need assistance with a `SQL` query. I've executed the below query that I thought was supposed to show results where the `START_DATE_TIME` is older than 6 `months`. However, as you can see below, it is pulling records where the START_DATE_TIME is less than 6 months old. Anyone know how to get around this?

```
SELECT ESPADMIN.ESP_APPLICATION.APPL_NAME,
       ESPADMIN.ESP_APPLICATION.START_DATE_TIME
FROM ESPADMIN.ESP_APPLICATION
WHERE(ESPADMIN.ESP_APPLICATION.START_DATE_TIME > add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -06));
```

A few results from query showing `START_DAT_TIME`:

```
5/21/2017 10:00:35 AM
5/21/2017 2:00:40 PM
```

Comment: Change the > to a < ?

Answer (score 0):

Within the where statement of your query, you need to alter the > to a <

```
  select ESPADMIN.ESP_APPLICATION.APPL_NAME, 
  ESPADMIN.ESP_APPLICATION.START_DATE_TIME 
  from ESPADMIN.ESP_APPLICATION
  where (ESPADMIN.ESP_APPLICATION.START_DATE_TIME < 
  add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'),-06))
```

Dates within a table are treated as integers when doing a mathematical comparison, so as dates get later, the integer gets higher.  To go backwards mathematically would be a less than.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The query does work better but for whatever reason I am missing data from what it seems to be, the whole month of March. When I ran the query today and the newest date i got back was 2/28 when I have confirmed that I do have data for the month of March but it is not pulling it for whatever reason.